# Unresolved external symbol c++ for inheritance and constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
//Baseclass.h
class Baseclass {
private:
    uint8_t index;
public:
    Baseclass(uint8_t index);
}

//Baseclass.cpp
#include "Baseclass.h"
Baseclass::Baseclass(uint8_t index) {
    index = index;
};

//Subclass.h
#include "Baseclass.h"
class Subclass : public Baseclass {
public:
    Subclass();
};

//Subclass.cpp
#include "Subclass.h"
#include "Baseclass.h"
Subclass::Subclass() : Baseclass(0) {};
```

What am I missing? I kept getting LNK2019 Error

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Baseclass::Baseclass(unsigned char)" (??Baseclass@@QAE@E@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Subclass::Subclass(void)" (??Subclass@@QAE@XZ)
```

Comment: Looks like you did not compile BaseClass.cpp while compiling.

Comment: It's not related to your problem, but `index = index` is self assignment, didn't you mean `this -> index = index`.

Comment: Ok I just rewrote the BaseClass.cpp manually. Apparently I have some think like "mac file error" :( Spent 1 hour just because of invisiable character bug ? Thanks though!

Comment: I have a feeling that you have more compiler errors/warnings than what you've included.  Please paste all of the output, because I believe the answer to your question lies within.

Comment: @buratino I got it working now and everything is perfect. BaseClass.cpp did not get compiled due to some warning that I ignore : (

Comment: Exactly as I thought :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It couldn't link Baseclass constructor. Are you sure there are no issues with compiling it? If you copy pasted all of the code you lack semicolon at the end of baseclass.

Comment: Thank you it is working now. Yes Baseclass.cpp was not compiling. It was warning me about Mac file or end of file syntax or something. But I deleted the file and reworte it!